# PHP object holding XML data

Tags: php, xml

How to check whether any data is returned in Object `$twitter_xml` for query `abc` or its empty?

Following is the code:

```
 $url="http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=abc";
 $twitter_xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

Comment: You will always get an XML response. What element are you looking for in it?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a count of items:

```
count($twitter_xml->channel->item);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what Twitter returns, but you should be able to do an `isset()` on a value you expect to exist.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

E.g.

```
if(isset($twitter_xml->name))
{
    // XML has a 'name' element
}
else
{
    // No 'name' element
}
```